# data.frame and table in R

Tags: r, dataframe

i have a list of movies and List of workers like directors and players for each film.
i need to show a list of the movies and the number of workers to each movie with the help of table and dataframe.

[What the result should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3ZE0.png)

but when i make the table to director and onther table to workers and want to make dataframe from them it gives me an error because there is a different amount of lines because they don't add to the table movies without workers to the workers table or and the same with director.

any help please?
thank you,

```
numDirectors <- table(imdb.players[imdb.players$role == "Director",]$id)
numWriter <- table(imdb.players[imdb.players$role == "Writer",]$id)
               
numall.df <- data.frame(numDirectors,numWriter)
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use `in%` instead of `==` to get multiple 'role' elements and apply the `table` once on the 'role' and 'id' columns

```
as.data.frame(table(subset(imbd.players, role %in% c("Director", "Writer"), 
      select = c(role, id))))
```